# How to turn off the odd blank page beside my page in Word office?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a weird problem. I don’t know what I have done.

It have a blank page next to my page which like a extend but O cant insert any text. It look like a margin but it not. Just see my demo image, you will see the ruler in my office.

[image]

When you print it, it also have it too.

I try to copy and pasted it in new document by all of type paste. But it still have this.

It doesn’t have it when you have a new document or other file. 
When I try to open this document from a zip file, it still occur.

Any idea?

Comment: Showing the same screenshot with visible paragraph marks would help a lot. It seems to be something related to paragraph formatting or page layout. Do you have only this paragraph in the document? Does deleting it removes the extra page? Any unusual settings in page layout(e.g. Book printing)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be the Markup Area.

[image: Markup Area screenshot]
[<sup>The image links to a larger version of itself.</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY5Ca.png)

This can appear if you have Tracked Changes or Comments
*anywhere in your document* (i.e., if you scroll, you may find them). 
You’ll want to familiarize yourself with the “REVIEW” tab. 
The controls in the “Comments” section will let you find Comments;
similarly,
the controls in the “Changes” section will let you find Tracked Changes. 
The “Tracking” section gives you ways to control
how/if the Markup Area is displayed.  For example,
you might want to change “All Markup” to “Simple Markup” or “No Markup”:

[image: the “REVIEW” tab]

or use the “Show Markup” control to be more selective.

Answer (score 0):

You could always [reset your Microsoft Word user options & registry settings](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/822005), if nothing else works.

> "When you troubleshoot unusual behavior in the program or in a
>   document, first determine whether the problem might be caused by
>   formatting, options, or settings. If the behavior occurs in multiple
>   documents, we recommend that you try to reset Microsoft Word to the
>   program's default settings."